# How to pass GET value to bootstrap modal

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

i have a bootstrap modal and am trying to pass a unique value through GET to the modal but the modal keeps getting the same unique value instead of the value of the table row i clicked. Been struggling with this for days and cant seem to figure out why it's not working. The code is below

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM houses"; 
    $q=$conn->query($sql);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['nickname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['state']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['city']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
    <td>    
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="view_property.php?house=<?php echo $row['nickname']; ?>"><i class="icon_check_alt2"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="edit_property.php?house=<?php echo $row['nickname']; ?>"><i class="icon_plus_alt2"></i></a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myDelete"><i class="icon_close_alt2"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div id="myDelete" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Property</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Are you sure you want to pull out this property from your list of Properties, as all data regarding this property will be lost permanently <?php echo $row['nickname']; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="view_property.php?house=<?php echo $row['nickname']; ?>">Delete</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean

Comment: i have a table that is populated from my database as shown above, when i click on delete on a speceifc row in that table i want to be directed to a pop up message(modal) which says are u sure u want to delete with a delete button underneath. when i click on delete button in that modal, i want it to delete the row i selected initially. To do this am passing that rows unique id to the modal so that i can use it to delete the row. The problem is, it is sending only one unique id no matter the row i click, it still passes the same id to the modal instead of the id for that row @jekaby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HTML` ids should be unique, you're using the same id for every iteration.

Try using:

```
id="myDelete<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"
data-target="#myDelete<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"
```

Hope this helps!